# Xampp apache not starting showing dll file missing

Tags: apache, xampp

When i try to run apache on xampp it shows the following error .
[image]

I updated my windows 8.1 and I tried to install c++ redistributable 2015 it also shows error "Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable Setup Fails [0x80240017] ".
How can i fix that error ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I uninstall the "Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable" and update the windows. Then setup the Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable again.Its work !
  **Update for Windows (KB2999226)** I think this is the important update about to fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

copy one from the **php** folder to your apache **bin** folder. that will solve the problem

Answer (score -1):

Try this

Go to services and stop World Wide Web Publishing Services.

And reinstall Xampp.

Answer (score -1):

xampp 1.8 3 download for windows . this version is properly work not any problem. link are provided

https://sourceforge.net/projects/xampp/files/XAMPP%20Windows/1.8.3/

i am 100% sure